# I want item keys and item values to be match with query1 and query2 using if statement

Tags: python

```
def product():
    item = {
        'Bananas': 3,
        'Apples' : 2,
        'Oranges' : 4,
        'Pineapple' : 6,
        'Strawberry' : 5
    }

query1 = input('Write product: ')
query2 = int(input('Write quantity: '))

print(product())
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to look up an entry from `item` using `query1` as the key?

Comment: You will only be printing `None` since you don't return a value

Comment: Also, I rolled back to your original since I didn't want to assume your indentation, but please fix your formatting.

Comment: Where's the conditionals mentioned in the title??

Comment: If the problem you're having is with that "Applied conditional statement a lot of times", you have to show us that conditional statement that didn't work, and explain what "didn't work" means (exception traceback, expected vs. actual results, etc.), or we can't debug it for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.   
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are looking for True/False as the function's result.

```
 def product():
    item = { 'Bananas': 3, 'Apples' : 2, 'Oranges' : 4, 'Pineapple' : 6, 'Strawberry' : 5 }
    query1 = input('Write product: ')
    query2 = int(input('Write quantity: '))
    if query1 in item:
        if item[query1] == query2:
            return True
    return False

print(product())
```